# How to read my socket messages

Tags: c++, algorithm, sockets, sendmessage

I am reading variable bytes messages from sockets in C. But there is a problem when some byte in any message is \0. It is split in 2 parts and only first half is sent. There is also receiving problem on the client side as well.

Please suggest any format, I can use.

One solution, I have is to sent the size of the message first and then send the rest of message. This will solve the problem but the processing becomes complex.

I am looking for any other cleaner solutions ?

```
/**
    Send data to the connected host
 */
bool send_data(const char* data) {
    //Send some data
    if (sendto(sock, data, strlen(data), 0,
            (const struct sockaddr *) &server, length) < 0) {
        perror("Send failed ");
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "Data sent: length=" << strlen(data) << " \n";

    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(server.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    std::cerr << "server.sin_addr=" << str << std::endl;

    return true;
}

/**
    Receive data from the connected host
 */
void receive(char * buffer, size_t size) {

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if (recvfrom(sock, buffer, size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from, (socklen_t*) & length) < 0) {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(from.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    std::cerr << "from.sin_addr=" << str << std::endl;

}
```

The data I am sending is just integers converted casted to `char *`. Well some integers are small, so there upper bytes are mostly 00000000. hence my problem.

Comment: Is the data you send text or binary? If you send binary data you can't use text functions (like e.g. `strlen`). Much more than this is impossible to say without seeing any code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "It is split in 2 parts and only first half is sent". Why do you not think that is because your code is incorrect? Because you certainly can send and receive messages with `\0` in it if you have the right code to do that. But we can't point out the problem if we can't see the code.

Comment: `strlen(data)` is your problem. As pointed out already you can't use any string function if your data is binary (which it is if you want to include `\0`s in it). One possible fix is for the `send_data` function to take a length parameter.

Comment: "The data I am sending is just integers converted casted to char *". That update just confirms your data is very much binary and not text. You must not use the string functions on it. And I don't see what is so complex about sending the size first. That's a pretty standard way of operating.

Comment: @kaylum, yes, sending size first is not difficult. I was just checking which other ways are used for it?

Comment: Yes there are. But none of them are necessarily any simpler. And not sure if you can use them because we don't have your full requirements. For example, if you know the data never has a specific value (e.g `0xFFFFFFFF`) then you can use that as the delimiter.

Comment: I think sending the size first is going to be as simple as it gets tbh.

Comment: If you're using TCP, remember that it's a streaming protocol and the stream can arrive at the receiver in pieces of any size, and you need to structure that into messages yourself.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Its UDP.

Comment: @ee2: Well, in that case, you already know the full size of the message (`recvfrom()` gives that to you), so you could just divide that by the byte size of the integers you are sending, assuming they are all the same byte size.  But, since you are sending binary messages, they have structure to them, so you should code for that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you have access to both server and client code.

You said you know the size of your message, so you could prepare your message before sending it, looking for any `\0` character and replacing replacing it with a *unique* byte sequence you could identify on the client side, replacing it back by the original character.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is caused by casting integers directly to character arrays and sending them, then I would suggest writing the integers to an ostringstream (available in the C++ standard library), extracting the integers by calling the ostringstreams str() method, and then sending the formatted strings over your socket.  This will give you the character representations of your integers and should fix any formatting problems.